# xsl:for-each and xsl:sort repeat the same list

Tags: sorting, xslt, foreach, apache-fop, dita-ot

I'm trying to sort a list of items in a <dl>. The XML is tagged like this. I assigned "sort" to the outputclass attribute to indicate this specific <dl> is to be sorted.

```
<dl outputclass="sort"> 
        <dlentry> 
          <dt> Ant 
          </dt> 
          <dd> 
             <p> A Java-based software tool for automating builds. 
             </p> 
          </dd> 
        </dlentry> 
        <dlentry> 
          <dt> Node 
          </dt> 
          <dd> 
             <p> A level in a document hierarchy. 
             </p> 
          </dd> 
        </dlentry>
        <dlentry> 
          <dt> DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture) 
          </dt> 
          <dd> 
             <p> An XML-based authoring model based on inheritance and specialization. 
             </p> 
          </dd> 
        </dlentry> 
....
</dl>
```

I know that <xsl:sort> needs to be nested in a <xsl:for-each>. After several attempts, this is the XSLT that has consistently generated sorted text for a PDF:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../dlentry">
   <xsl:sort select="dt"/>
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="dlentry.dd__content" margin-left="0pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dt"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dd"/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that it repeats the sorted list for each <dlentry> in my list:

> **Ant**
> A Java-based software tool for automating builds.
> **DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture)**
> An XML-based authoring model based on inheritance and specialization.
> **Node**
> A level in a document hierarchy.
> **Ant**
> A Java-based software tool for automating builds.
> **DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture)**
> An XML-based authoring model based on inheritance and specialization.
> **Node**
> A level in a document hierarchy.
> **Ant**
> A Java-based software tool for automating builds.
> **DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture)**
> An XML-based authoring model based on inheritance and specialization.
> **Node**
> A level in a document hierarchy.

How do I get a sorted list, and only have it generated once instead of for each <dlentry>? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact** result (as code) you expect to get in the given example.

Comment: We really need to see the context from which your code is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only showing us a part of your code, so we can only guess.

Still, your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../dlentry">
```

can work only if it is called from the context of `dlentry`, and if so called, will execute the code for **all**  `dlentry` elements, not only the current one, but also all its siblings.

Apparently you are doing this for every `dlentry`, so in the end the code is executed 3x3 times.

Instead you should be doing something like:

```
<xsl:template match="dl">
    <xsl:for-each select="dlentry">
       <xsl:sort select="dt"/>
       <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="dlentry.dd__content" margin-left="0pt">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dt"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dd"/>
       </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. What I did was move the sorting code to the template for dl so it used the correct context. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to click Accept.